# How to know which program has done CPI for our program?

Tags: solana-program, cpi

Suppose, If we have a Program-A which can be called by other programs and users.
If a program does a CPI to Program-A, How to know which program is trying to call our program(Program-A).

Answer (score 1):

You should aggregate & parse all transaction history of your program.
If you could find any of your program's instructions in innerInstructions you should check program addresses of the parent instruction.
It will tell you which program cpi called to your program.

Comment: Can you please provide any references on how to do that ?

Comment: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/4GmZzpZySNSCvavJ64b7jPvq5b1cyFojYyv1EJgJmp5s1hgFKh7AV5ZNpPh6uR7pA4yJ1WgQtnM4jA71iiUtNuGu

For example you can find transfer IX of token program in inner instruction of close_slip IX. https://i.imgur.com/YQbxqZM.png

Now you can see Divvy House program made a cpi call to Token Program.